# How to fix 'syntax error' in itertools module for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to define **a** to be used for future personal use.  I tried before with partial success and it won't print the permutations. Just a memory address. I tried to find the permutations list but it wouldn't show up. I even used the memory address and same thing popped up on the screen.

```
   >>> a == itertools.permutations(['+', '$', '#']):
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        a == itertools.permutations(['+', '$', '#']):
                                                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    >>> a = itertools.permutations(['+', '$', '#']):
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        a = itertools.permutations(['+', '$', '#']):
                                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

-

```
>>> print a
<itertools.permutations object at 0x7eff4c8ede90>
>>>ctypes.cast(a, ctypes.py_object).value

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 503, in cast
 return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
 ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: Remove the colon

Comment: `a == itertools.permutations(['+', '$', '#']):` doesn't make sense, you're trying to use it as a condition; removing the colon won't help because then you'll just get a Boolean and it probably can't be True. I assume you want `=` for assignment, instead of `==` which is for comparison. If you _did_ want to check for equality, you need an `if`

Comment: @roganjosh Note that this appears to be an interactive REPL session and there is no `if` in the code that was entered.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Premature enter. I edited :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Is there any kind of comparison to be done, or you just want the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is closer to what I think you want. You just need to remove the colon from the end. Note that `=` is used for assigning a value to a variable whereas `==` is used for comparing two values.